# Ms Access Run-time Error 3070 finding unknown field name or expression

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to open a form in MS Access (Office 365).  I am using the following VBA code:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "CommunityAccountList", acNormal, , , , , "Community = " & Me.CommunityID.Value
```

The code was working fine, and then it started producing the error:

**Run-time error '3070': The Microsoft database engine does not recognize '5239' as a valid field name or expression.**

I preceded this line of code with 'MsgBox "Community = " & Me.CommunityID.Value' which produced the following popup:  "Community = 1".  I cannot figure out where Access is getting the **5239** from.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The filter criteria is shown in wrong argument. I don't see how it could have ever worked. Delete 3 commas.

Comment: I just tested and I don't get error but also does not apply filter. So something else is happening. You have this criteria in OpenArgs argument. Is opening form trying to do something with OpenArgs?

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you are applying a WHERE clausule when opening the form, it should be something like `DoCmd.OpenForm "CommunityAccountList", acNormal, ,  "Community = " & Me.CommunityID.Value`, as suggested by @June7.

Comment: The Community=Me.CommunityID.Value is an OpenArgs, not a search filter.  I am merely passing a variable required to open the form.  This worked previously on this line, as well as in other places I used the DoCmd.OpenForm.  I still do not understand where Access is getting 5239 from.

Comment: What do you do with the string passed by OpenArgs? Whatever that is, must be what is causing error. If you want opening form filtered then put that criteria in WHERE CONDITION argument.

Comment: The variable passed by OpenArgs is inserted into a select statement for the form being opened.  I use the exact (cut and pasted) line in another form and it opens the target form error-free.  I have seen runtime error 3070 before, and it was easy to debug because it identifies the field name causing the error.  In this case, it is stating 5239 is the culprit.  How can I debug this if I cannot identify 5239?

Comment: Tried this on three other computers, as mine had just completed installing another Windows update, which I thought may be causing this error, but I got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved:  The issue was not with the DoCmd line or the query being run.  The issue was on the form being opened.  Somehow I copied 5239 into the Order By property field for the form.

Comment: This post solved a similar issue for me. I had not spotted a reference in a order by on a report that I had imported from another database. Thanks